# How to set hex mode to lcd if total value is greater than 99?

Tags: python, pyqt4

Anyone has any idea on how to make numbers equal to or bigger than 100 appear as hex mode in pyqt lcd? Here is the code:

```py
def showValue(self):
    sender = self.sender()
    if sender.isChecked():
        self.lcdValue += sender.GetValue()
        self.lcdNumber.display("0" +str(self.lcdValue))
    else:
        self.lcdValue -= sender.GetValue()
        self.lcdNumber.display("0" +str(self.lcdValue))

    for self.lcdValue in (99, 164):
        self.lcdNumber.setHexMode()
```

It returns funny values in hex mode and does not do addition or subtraction anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm *preeeetty* sure this isn't what you meant:

> ```
> for self.lcdValue in (99, 164):
> ```

Try this instead:

```
if 99 < self.lcdValue < 164:
```

Don't forget to reset it at the beginning of the method, since you don't want it like this permanently.

Comment: This can't work either. My values are still messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Like Ignacio mentioned, you have to reset it, you can do it like this:

```
def showValue(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        if sender.isChecked():
            self.lcdValue += sender.GetValue()
        else:
            self.lcdValue -= sender.GetValue()

        self.lcdNumber.display("000000" + str(self.lcdValue))

        if 99 < self.lcdValue < 164:
            self.lcdNumber.setHexMode()
        else:
            self.lcdNumber.setDecMode()
```

Comment: It still doesn't do the addition properly. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Can it be done without reseting the whole program?

Comment: it works fine for me. Can you place what output you get for values 80, 120 150 164

Comment: For 80+40, I got 78 which is wrong. I should be getting 120 in hexadecimal format. For 80+20, I got 64 instead.

Comment: that is not wrong. hexadecimal of 120 is 78, and hax of 100 is 64. You can use Programmer calculator to confirm that

Comment: yea i just figured it out that it is not hex mode. This is another mode but thanks for pointing it out to me!